# Redirect url without changing the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are a lot of answers available for this but none of them worked for me. I am stuck with this very familiar issue. I have made a website wherein i have to make customised urls for all my franchisees. But all these customised urls should take back to homepage.

Eg. if franchisee enters following url : `www.example.com/franchisee/john` it should redirect the franchisee to `www.example.com` but the browser url should remain `www.example.com/franchisee/john`

I have tried this by modifying .htaccess file but it shows page not found(404) error. Any help will be appreciable. I am new to .htaccess.

Here is .htaccess code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/franchisee/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

**EDIT** :
Here is the complete .htaccess file. This file is present under the docroot folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/franchisee/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+$
    RewriteRule ^franchisee/[\w.-]+/?$ / [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `proxy` or `P` flag here. Use this rule without `R` flag to silently rewrite to `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^franchisee/[\w.-]+/?$ / [L]
```

Comment: Still not working. It keeps the browser url intact to `www.example.com/franchisee/john` but doesn't redirect to `www.example.com` and continues to give 404 error

Comment: No it won't redirect as redirect means changing the URL. Where is your .htaccess located? Also show your complete .htaccess in question

Comment: You don't need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` line in your .htaccess and also tell where is your .htaccess located? Is it in `/franchisee/` directory?

Comment: .htaccess file is in the docroot folder. There is no such physical path `www.example.com/franchisee/<franchisee-name>`. The requirement is to distribute this url and whenever any franchisee hits this url i want them to see the home page but the url should remain intact to `www.example.com/franchisee/<franchisee-name>`.

Comment: In that case you have some config issue as above rule works pretty well on my Apache.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?